# How do I keep indoor air quailty high without letting in the outdoor air?

Tags: air-quality, planting

The outdoor air is polluted. Is it possible to keep the indoor air quality high without letting outdoor air in? Maybe with plants?

Comment: It would help to know what the nature of the pollution is.

Comment: you need an air filter. hepa, ultrasonic, electrostatic, whatever, you need a filter.

Comment: Having a lot of house plants will not do anything for indoor air quality.

Answer (score 0):

Consider sources of volatile and off-gassing materials, pet type, amount of people and pets, what you cook and the kitchens exhaust design, use of candles, how often cleaning is done, and anything that combusts. You then design around that with the suggestions mentioned. Also consider the air quality in your neighborhood and how airtight your house is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how my house is set up. I have an electronic air cleaner that I clean 4 times a year and I install a cut to size filter called "the web Absorber" that I purchase from either HomeDepot or Lowes. I use this filter as a pre-filter to take out some of the dirt and a lot of the odors. ( IT has a charcoal filter and a regular filter since MY wife can smell any odor  from 1 a mile away ). I also run the furnace fan 24/7 as I have done in the 2 houses we have owned over the last 40 years. A few times a year my wife opens all the windows for an hour or so and vents out the house. So far I have never had a motor wear out or give us any problems. We have no pets anymore and the kids are gone.